# What is Humiliation?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How do you get the "Complete all Humiliation unlocks" Calling Card? What is defined as a "humiliation"? I have managed to get 16/25 without ever playing Gun Game/Sticks and Stones.

Comment: The COD tag does apply. Read my edit comment.

Comment: Either you are asking about a single game or the series.  Both tags are not needed.

Comment: Why am I not allowed to tag this question with Call of Duty when the answer may pertain to the entire series in addition to this game. Have you ever read: "A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions." I am simply categorizing my question with the Call of Duty series since the answer may be the same throughout all of the games.

Comment: If you want to ask about the whole series, only use [tag:call-of-duty].  Otherwise, use [tag:call-of-duty-black-ops-2].  Both are not needed.

Comment: I disagree with you 100% but I will remove the tag to make you happy. I am posting about my specific call-of-duty-black-ops-2 question even though it pertains to the series.

Comment: Side note:  You don't have to use the game title in the question title.  Using the tag is sufficient.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot This is a lot of arguing over a small issue and the nitpicking is very discouraging for a new user. The edits have not improved the clarity or usefulness of the question, so you've gained little and in the process potentially lost a user. You've also invoked an angry response (answer probably deleted). That's not a trade I can agree with.

Comment: @SadlyNot There is a difference between "nitpicking" and trying to explain how the site works to a new user. I see nothing wrong with what was done here.

Comment: I am not a "new user" in any way shape or form. My reputation on this site is lower, but I am majorly from Stackoverflow. I disagree with what has been said in response to my tags.

Comment: @ardavis: When tagging questions we like to strive for a minimalist approach, using as few tags as possible. Part of this is that (in most situations) a question will either be tagged with the game name, or the series name, but not both. The tag used is the more relevant one, which best indicates what the question is about. In this case your question is about Black Ops 2, and not the series as a whole, so the Black ops 2 tag applies. One of the reasons behind this is that the tags have two very distinct purposes: series tags are for questions about the series, and game tags are for...

Comment: ...questions about a specific game in the series. Tagging the question with both is something the community feels is redundant, and just makes it harder to users to find relevant questions.

Comment: @SadlyNot I was simply trying to explain this site's tagging conventions.  I was not rude in any way as the user who posted the answer chose to be.  If anyone has any more to say on the tagging issue, it should be moved to [chat].

Comment: @OrigamiRobot You were not intentionally rude, merely helpful, but I still feel like it was taken that way. I wouldn't of been able to do better myself, but I felt like sharing how I felt about it. For those of you who didn't see the flame comment I was only concerned because that comment came up.

Comment: @ardavis No offense by using the word "new" - you have been a stack exchange user longer than me. Each stack exchange site has slight differences in rules despite efforts to consolidate that, so considering your rep here is not as much as what you have on Stack Overflow I thought you may not immediately get why the rules are the way they are. The "no game name in title" rule is pretty Arqade specific AFAIK but I *think* that all sites take a minimalistic approach to tag rules.

Comment: This has been a very interesting discussion actually. Thanks for everyone who took the time to think about it and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure in Black Ops 2, but in MW3, humiliation was composed of 17 challenges :

```
Hot Potato              I. Kill 5 enemies with thrown back grenades.
                        II. Kill 10 enemies with thrown back grenades.

Car Bomb                I. Kill 5 enemies by destroying cars.
                        II. Kill 10 enemies by destroying cars.

Backstabber             Stab an enemy in the back with your knife.

Slow But Sure           Kill an enemy while being stunned by a stun grenade.

Misery Loves Company    Kill yourself and 1 enemy by cooking a grenade without throwing it.

Ouch                    Kill an enemy with a rifle-mounted grenade launcher without detonation. (Direct impact)

Rival                   Kill the same enemy 5 times in a single match.

Cruelty                 Kill an enemy, pick up his weapon, then kill him with his own weapon.

Think Fast              Finish an enemy off by hitting them with a frag grenade. (Direct impact)

Think Fast Stun         Finish an enemy off by hitting them with a stun grenade. (Direct impact)

Think Fast Flash        Finish an enemy off by hitting them with a flash grenade. (Direct Impact)

Return To Sender        Kill 1 enemy by shooting their own explosive.

Blindfire               Kill an enemy while you are still dazed by a flashbang.

Hard Landing            Kill an enemy that is in mid-air.

Extreme Cruelty         Kill every member of the enemy team (at least 4 enemies) without dying.

Tango Down              Kill every member of the enemy team. (4 enemy minimum)

Counter-MVP             Kill the #1 player on the enemy team 10 times in a single match.
```

They must be pretty close to that in Black Ops 2.

Edit : BTW, source is [Call of Duty Wikia](http://callofduty.wikia.com)

Comment: I feel like [I've seen these before](http://www.cod4central.com/cod4-challenges-humiliation.php) ...

Comment: Yup, pretty close.. I guess they're almost the same in BO2.

Comment: **Return To Sender**        Kill 1 enemy by shooting their own explosive.  Is this possible? I thought your own explosive cant hur t you.

Comment: Yes it does hurt you. Try throwing a grenade just in front of you and stand on it when it explodes :). Same thing for all the explosives (C4, claymore, boucing betty, semtex, but also flash, concussion, ...).

Comment: And that challenge is hell... I'd say in MW3 the "easiest" (with a **lot** of luck) is shooting the enemy's bouncing betty.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal See the A-killed-B-with-weaponX lines on the left? Sometimes there appears no A, but just weaponX and B. WeaponX is either a grenade or some air support.

Comment: .. or a javelin .. :D

Answer (score 1):

In BO2 you can go to Barracks in multiplayer then go to challenges. Then head to the assignments challenges the third one over is humiliation . Once you click on that you can see the 26 things you need to unlock if your confused about one in particular just post about it and someone or myself will gladly explain.

Comment: Telling them to check the requirements doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: I disagree, he's telling them where the humiliation challenges are, so he can see "what is defined as a humilation"

Comment: @turbo Telling you where to find the challenges does absolutely nothing to tell you how to get it.

Comment: The only difference between the accepted answer and this one, is that the accepted answer took the time to copy&paste/type out the actual challenges.  It's probably more convenient to look at the challenges in game as you're playing because they track progress.  In fact, the accepted answer overtly states that it lists the challenges for MW3, not even BO2.

Comment: ill upvote this answer just to get it back to 0 score. The answer itself is correct but not complete. If he actually ads some examples of the challenges this should be the approved answer.